# PythonShellError: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, node.js

i have already installed pandas but it is still showing no module found when trying to run a python script from nodejs using python shell.

```
const route = require('express').Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
const path = require('path');

route.post('/report', (req, res) => {
  var myPythonScriptPath = path.join(__dirname + '/report_gen.py');
  var pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);
  var message = req.body.zone;
  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    res.send({ msg: message });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you install pandas in the same python environment as the one used by nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

You need this line in the start of your code

```
import pandas as pd
```